# How to ignore previous async effects when useEffect is called again?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a simple component that makes an async request when some state changes:

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResult(state).then(setResult);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>{result}</div>
  );
};
```

The problem is, sometimes the `state` changes twice in a short lapse of time, and the `fetchResult` function can take a very different amount of time to resolve according to the `state` value, so sometimes this happens:

[image: Effect calls sequence diagram]

As you can guess, as `state` now is `state2` and not `state1` anymore, I would like `result` to be `result2`, *ignoring the response received in the `then` of the -obsolete- first effect call*.

Is there any clean way to do so?

Comment: Try to clean up fetch with AbortController. https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-cleanup-async-effects/,  here is a nice blog to show you how to do this in details.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you setup some kind of request cancellation method in the useEffect cleanup function.

For example with axios, it looks like that:

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    fetchResult({state, cancelToken: source.cancelToken }).then(setResult);
    return () => {
      source.cancel()
    }
  }, [state]);


  return (
    <div>{result}</div>
  );
};
```

You have a similar API with fetch called [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

What this will do is it will cancel the stale requests if your state changed so only the last one will resolve (and set result).

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this... but my initial thought would be if you have the state in the response, you could check if the state fetched matches the current state. If not, then the state has changed since the request and you no longer care about the response so don't set it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResult(state).then((response) => {
      response.state === state ? setResult(response.data) : false;
    });
  }, [state]);
```

You might also be able to do it by keeping a record of the fetchedState on each request.. and again discard it if it no longer matches.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let fetchedState = state;
    fetchResult(fetchedState).then((response) => {
      fetchedState === state ? setResult(response) : false;
    });
  }, [state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built something like the below in order to only ever use the last result of the last request sent:

```
const REQUEST_INTERVAL = 2000

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = useState();
  const [result, setResult = useState()

  const requestIndex = useRef(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const thisEffectsRequestIndex = requestIndex.current + 1
    requestIndex.current = thisEffectsRequestIndex

    setTimeout(() => {
      if(thisEffectsRequestIndex === requestIndex.current) {
        fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
        .then((response) => { 
          if(thisEffectsRequestIndex === requestIndex.current) {
            setResult(response.json())
          }
        })
      }
    })
    , REQUEST_INTERVAL)
  }, [inputState]) 

  return <div>{result}</div>
}
```